# Applying UK Citizenship from Northern Cyprus

Tags: work, uk-citizens, turkish-citizens, northern-cyprus

I have double citizenship from Turkey and Northern Cyprus. I know that getting UK visa from NC is very easy, and I also heard of many cypriots became UK citizen. I really consider applying for myself too, I studied computer science and job offers are quite delightful there. What advantages do I have for being a NC citizen?

Comment: Advantage of being a Northern Cyprus citizen? Or a British citizen over being a Northern Cyprus citizen?

Comment: @Relaxed Advantage of being a Northern Cyprus citizen on my way to be accepted as a British citizen.

Comment: Would this be off-topic here and more on topic for expatriates?

Comment: Where did you hear that many Cypriots become UK citizens? It's less than 50 people a year!

Comment: @GayotFow Northern Cyprus' population is currently 300.000 so 50 people means one in 6.000 lol

Comment: Are you sure, Northern Cyprus isn't recognized by UK so how can they allow you to apply for citizenship.

Comment: @DumbCoder Its not recognized but UK has a base on that island, you can get visa in half a day from north side.

Comment: `visa in half a day from north side` That would be a record anywhere for issuing a British visa. And I am not joking. But I haven't seen any evidence of, on the UK gov website, of allowing NC citizens to apply for UK citizenship, considering you aren't even resident in UK and moreover NC isn't recognized by UK government.

Comment: NC is actually like a big village. I'll research more. Thanks.

Comment: @DumbCoder, you won't find anything specific to NC citizens. At one point somebody who lived on the sovereign base could apply to become a BOC. Big difference!  The OP probably has BOC confused with BC. The question is misconceived.